# Can't install libapache2-mod-passenger for Apache 2.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

I'm currently using https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/apache/oss/trusty/install_passenger.html to install Passenger on Ubuntu 12.04 running Apache 2.4.16.

```
# sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-passenger
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-passenger : Depends: apache2-mpm-worker (>= 2.2.9-9) but it is not going to be installed or
                                     apache2-mpm-prefork (>= 2.2.9-9) but it is not going to be installed or
                                     apache2-mpm-itk (>= 2.2.9-9) but it is not going to be installed or
                                     apache2-mpm-event (>= 2.2.9-9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: can you translate the error message? It is not in english.

Comment: Done, please check

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve this dependency.

```
libapache2-mod-passenger : Depends on: apache2-mpm-worker (>= 2.2.9-9) but it is not going to be installed or
                                           apache2-mpm-prefork (>= 2.2.9-9) but it is not going to be installed or
                                           apache2-mpm-itk (>= 2.2.9-9) sbut it is not going to be installed or
                                           apache2-mpm-event (>= 2.2.9-9) but it is not going to be installed or
```

Try with this. It might work. Also after resolving these dependencies then start the installation process again.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker libapache2-mod-fcgid php5-cgi
```

Comment: `apache2-mpm-worker` is for 2.2.9 and I got Apache 2.4.16 and I don't think it says `... but it is not going to be installed` for no reason?

Comment: Try to install `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fcgid php5-cgi`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using a different repository:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/web/libapache2-mod-passenger

This one is compatible ith Apache 2.4.16